# Is a local-only MAMP installation secure?

Tags: mamp, security

I just installed a basic MAMP server (on a Macbook Air 11" running OSX Lion) with no settings changed except for some php.ini things like "memory", "file_upload", etc that are more script related.

- I use this local server for my own "web application" that I use ONLY locally, on my macbook air and only me ever needs to have access to it.
- My PHP script go online to fetch data from a couple of websites using `fopen`
- I'm not using any antivirus software or any other security softwares of any type other than whatever comes standard with the Mac

So my questions are :

- is this secure?
- can someone from outside my private network (1) see my web application and (2) access it in any ways?
- is the fact of having MAMP running opening any security hole in a OSX Lion that I should be aware of?
- If I would install it in a WAMP (Windows 7) installation, using the same basic settings + Norton Antivirus, would that be safe?

Thanks a lot for enlighting me

Joel

Comment: What's Apache's `Listen` configuration?

Comment: I checked the `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf` file and it said : `Listen 8888`. The `MAMP/conf/apache/original/httpd.conf` said : `Listen 80`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the configuration of your services to listen only to localhost if you don't want for external connections to be allowed.

In Apache, change `Listen 8888` to `Listen 127.0.0.1:8888`.  In MySQL, (and this may or may not be set already), make sure you have `bind-address=127.0.0.1` set.

Comment: I will still be able to use `fopen` to access websites and external data?

Comment: Sure, it won't restrict the code that's being executed.

Comment: Awsome, thanks a lot. Another thing, `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`is the file the server is using, right? The other one is like a backup, I imagine?

Comment: Also wanted to add that, without appropriate NAT entries in your home network, external users won't be able to reach your development site at all

Comment: I have a Time Capsule latest generation, should the address be "Listen 10.0.1.4:8888" instead? And where can I modify the bind-adress, I've been looking for an hour and can't find that?

Comment: If you only need to access it from the local system, use 127.0.0.1.  `bind-address` is a MySQL configuration option - there may already be one in `my.cnf`.  If there isn't, go ahead and add it.